# Xcode4 ExternalHosts in .plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cordova

I'm new to Xcode and Mac environment, I'm trying to set up a PhoneGap / Cordova app and I'm getting a

```
ERROR whitelist rejection
```

I did a thorough Google Search and everything said I needed to edit my .plist file and add to the ExternalHosts key.

Well my application didn't have an ExternalHosts key so from random pictures I saw on the web I added an ExternalHosts key as an array and attempted to add the sites I needed so now my Xcode .plist file looks something like this:

[image: Xcode]

As you can see I tried both the domain way and an actual URI, but I'm still getting the same whitelist rejection error.

Can someone point in the right direction of how to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I was attempting to add ExternalHosts to the app build file.

Found out the file I was looking for is under /Resources/Supporting Files/Cordova(|Phonegap).plist